# Problem pour implements RepositoryCustom with JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

here my big problem 
this is the code

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity")
public class Entity extends AbstractField { 
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private BigInteger lookupValueKey;
private short lookupFieldKey;
private String lookupToken;
private String lookupValueFr;
private String lookupValueEn;
private BigInteger master1LookupValueKey;
private BigInteger master2LookupValueKey;
private BigInteger master3LookupValueKey;

public interface EntityRepository extends CrudRepository<Entity , BigInteger>,  
EntityRepositoryCustom {

}public interface EntityRepositoryCustom  {
List<Entity > inOnlyTest(Short groupId, String employerNum, Short EntityKey);

}@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class EntityRepositoryImp implements EntityRepositoryCustom {


@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;
@Override
public List<LookupValue> inOnlyTest(Short groupId, String employerNum,
        Short lookupFieldKey) {
    StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("EntityListbyKEY");
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Short.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    .........
```

and the error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.bell.radar.demo.dao.LookupValueRepositoryCustom.inOnlyTest(java.lang.Short,java.lang.String,java.lang.Short)! No property inOnlyTest found for type LookupValue!
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:106) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:574) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:567) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1054) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:569) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:332) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       ... 59 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property inOnlyTest found for type LookupValue!
>       at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:311) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
>       at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:276) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.(Part.java:82) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.(PartTree.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:380) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.(PartTree.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.(PartTree.java:93) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       ... 85 common frames omitted

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect naming convention for the the implementation

```
public class EntityRepositoryImp implements EntityRepositoryCustom {}
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations)

> The most important part of the class name that corresponds to the
>   fragment interface is the **Impl** postfix.

Rename the implementation class to `EntityRepositoryImpl` and attempt the run

Update :

Another observation is that the interface method

```
List<Entity > inOnlyTest(
```

and its override in the implementation

```
public List<LookupValue> inOnlyTest
```

are not in sync . typo ?

Comment: Ok thanks R.G I change for EntityRepositoryImpl  and now it work fine cool